# How to get id from $http.get in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get, partial

Hi I am a newbie and learning angular.js. I want to get data from this url which is actually an API (http://ba.dev/businesses/businesspage/36) but i dont know how can i Write this thing in my controller.js file. Given is my code please explain me how can I get the data from the business having id=36.

```
var reControllers = angular.module('reControllers',[]);
reControllers.controller('RecentController', ['$scope','$http' ,function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('http://ba.dev/businesses/businesses').success(function(data){
        $scope.business = data;
     }); 
}]);

reControllers.controller('PageController', ['$scope','$http', '$routeParams' ,function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
    $http.get('http://ba.dev/businesses/businesspage').success(function(data){
        $scope.student = data;
        $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId; 
    }); 
}]);
```

Here is my app.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[
    'ngRoute',                                
    'reControllers'                   
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){   
    $routeProvider.                      
        when('/main',{               
        templateUrl : 'partials/main.html',
        controller : 'RecentController'
    }).
    when('/page/:itemId',{
        templateUrl : 'partials/page.html',
        controller  : 'PageController'
    }).
    otherwise({                   
        redirectTo: '/main'   
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id from URL using `$routeParams`

```
$http.get('http://ba.dev/businesses/businesspage/'+ $routeParams.itemId)
```

Thereafter add server side logic, get passed `itemId` from URL, perform needful operation for getting data from DB and return it back.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `then` instead of `success`, because it is deprecated. So, your code should be: `

```
$http.get('http://ba.dev/businesses/businesses').then(function(data){
 $scope.business = data;
 }); }]);.....
```

From AngularJS documentation:

```
    // Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

More info about route params: [AngularJS $routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Comment: Even if people shouldn't use the `success` and `error` (your tip is correct, of course) it doesn't answer the question. In fact, it  should be a complement of a suppose answer.